# Regex to identify HTML tags (as a regex repetition learning exercise ONLY!!)

Tags: regex

I'm very very new to regex. I'd managed to not touch it with a 10-foot pole for so long. And I tried my best to avoid it so far. But now a personal project is pushing me to learn it.

So I started. And I'm going through the tutorial located here:http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Currently I'm here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

My question is:

The tutorial says `<[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*>` will match an HTML tag.

But wouldn't it also match invalid html tags like - `<h11>` or `<h111>`?
Also how would it match the closing tags?

Edit - My question is very specific. I am referring to one particular example in one particular tutorial to clarify whether or not my understanding of repetitions is correct. Again, I REPEAT, I DO NOT care about html parsing with regex.

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1175077

Comment: You did not answer my question. I'm not using Regex to 'match HTML'. That is not my purpose. I'm taking this as an exercise to learn Regex. Forget HTML. My question is how is the example in this tutorial correct if its purpose is to match <h1> - <h6>? Wouldn't it match <h11> and <h111> as well?

Comment: To answer your question: yes it will match `<h111>`, and it won't match the closing tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: @MikeW Thanks, so my understanding was correct. Sorry I had to resort to SO. The tutorial website itself doesn't seem to have a comments/forum section.

Comment: @CasparKleijne No not a duplicate. My question is very specific. I was referring to one particular example in one particular tutorial to clarify whether or not my understanding of repetitions was correct. Again, I REPEAT, I DO NOT care about html parsing with regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any harm in answering your question seeing as how you are attempting to learn regex:

1) Yes, it will match invalid tags as well because it's any letter followed by any zero or more matches of another letter or a number.

2) It will not match closing tags (there would have to be a search for a `/` somewhere in there).

One more comment: one way people used to use to look for html tags inside a document was to look for the pattern of opening and closing brackets, like so:

```
<\/?[^>]*>
```

That's opening-bracket, an optional slash, (anything *but* a closing bracket)-repeated and then a closing bracket. Of course, I am not recommending anyone do this. It's merely left here as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I guess people are too quick to judge questions here without actually trying to understand what is being asked.

Comment: ^agreed on this particular topic. There's a bit of a choir that happens with the regex/html thing. Your question didn't seem to be the traditional ("I'm trying to learn regex in order to scrape the web", which, yes, I agree is not the right way to go about it).

Answer (score 0):

> The tutorial says <[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*> will match an HTML tag.
>
> But wouldn't it also match invalid html tags like -  or ?
>   Also how would it match the closing tags?

Yes, that will match `<h11>` as well as `<X098wdfhfdshs98fhj2hsdljhkvjnvo9sudvsodfih23234osdfs>`.

If you want to just match a letter followed by an optional single digit, so you'd match `<h1>`, then you want `<[A-Za-z][0-9]?>`

Comment: Or is this another correct way as well? - <[A-Za-z]*[1-6]{0,1}>

Comment: @DS: `?` can replace `{0,1}`. And of course that would also match `<z3>` or `<q7>`.